# Problem saving Neo4j 1:many @Relationship with polymorphic set

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

When saving the `Dater` class below with `Neo4jRepository::save` (`spring-data-neo4j-6.1.5`) the save hangs and never returns. I believe it has something to do with my `Dater` object having a relationship defined by a set referencing an interface instead of a class with a `@Node` annotation. Is this an issue for neo4j?

```
    //PersistentDaterMusicItem is interface. Is there a problem doing this?
    @Relationship(type = "LISTENS_TO_MUSIC")
    private Set<PersistentDaterMusicItem> musicItems = new HashSet<>();
```

```
//parent
@Node
public class Dater{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    //set of different implementations of PersistentDaterMusicItem
    @Relationship(type = "LISTENS_TO_MUSIC")
    private Set<PersistentDaterMusicItem> musicItems = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```
//inteface 1
public interface PersistentLibraryMusicItem extends PersistentDaterMusicItem{
    LocalDateTime getAddedDateTime();
}
```

```
//interface 2
public interface PersistentListenedMusicItem extends PersistentDaterMusicItem{
    LocalDateTime getListenedDateTime();
}
```

```
//impl 1 of PersistentDaterMusicItem
@Node
public class ListenedAppleSong extends AppleSong implements PersistentListenedMusicItem{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private final Long id;

}
```

```
//impl 2 of PersistentDaterMusicItem
@Node
public class LibraryAppleSong extends AppleSong implements PersistentLibraryMusicItem{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private final Long id;
  
}
```

Comment: Do you have the chance of upgrading to a newer version of Spring Data Neo4j?
6.1 is not officially patched anymore and the most current version out now is 6.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was unrelated to what I thought. My constructor to `ListenedAppleSong` took an argument that was not a field of the class. Since Spring data expects constructor args to exist as fields it was failing with error: `"Required property appleSong not found for class com.dapp.common.model.apple.ListenedAppleSong!"` Solution was to make sure all constructor args are fields in the class. Unfortunately this error was not thrown during execution and the code just hung so it took a while to debug.